# Move reference into smart pointer

Tags: c++, reference, smart-pointers, move-semantics

Is it possible in C++ to have a constructor that takes a reference to an object, and moves this into a smart pointer? Example:

```
class A {
public:
    A(std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>& v_ptr) : v_ptr(std::move(v_ptr)) {};

    // TODO: wanted constructor with this signature that ideally calls the first constructor
    A(std::vector<int>& v) {}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> v_ptr;
}
```

My intended usage of this class should be something like this:

```
A a({1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: A) Why a unique_ptr to a vector? vector already does memory ownership B) afaik usually if you intend to do a move like this you take things by value (your init list probably wont work with the ref signature since temporaries cant bind to non-const ref and a const ref cant be moved since moving modifies the source) C) `A(std::vector<int> v) : v_ptr(std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(std::move(v))) {}` ?

Comment: While legal, `unique_ptr` really should not be passed around using a non-const lvalue reference, as that doesn't convey the proper ownership semantics to the caller. It should be passed around by either value or rvalue reference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for this hint. I'll change that.

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, you're right. I used rvalue references in other locations of my code to achieve this syntax `f({1, 2, 3})`.

Comment: @Borgleader So, it's better to change the signature of `A` to `A(std::unique_ptr<...> v_ptr)`, so copy the unique pointer? However, I cannot get it compiled then: `../main.cpp:13:55: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int> >::unique_ptr(std::remove_reference<std::vector<int>&>::type)’`

Comment: @Green绿色 "*so copy the unique pointer?*" - `unique_ptr` can't be copied, only moved. The caller would have to use `std::move()` on a pre-existing `unique_ptr`, thus preserving ownership semantics. "*no matching function for call to ‘unique_ptr(std::vector<int>‌​)’*" - you can't construct a `unique_ptr` from a `vector`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So, the constructor would be `A(std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> v_ptr) : v_ptr(std::move(v_ptr)) {};` and the call to the constructor `A a(std::move(v_ptr));`? So move twice?

Comment: @Green绿色 no, because again, you can't construct a `unique_ptr` directly from a `vector`. Borgleader already showed you what you need (#C using `std::make_unique()`). Did you even try it yet?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, thanks. However, I'm a little bit confused about this reference and move thing.

Comment: @Green绿色 then I suggest you stop what you are doing and go brush up on the fundamentals of how smart pointers work. Get some [decent C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), if you need to. They will cover this in detail.